# Модальное окно конфликт js? проблема с DOM?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Приветствую есть [сайт](https://%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.%D1%80%D1%84/) на странице [комплекса](https://%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.%D1%80%D1%84/zhiloy-kompleks-samolet) модальное окно `JS`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    $('#mask').css({
      'width': maskWidth,
      'height': maskHeight
    });

    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
    $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

    $(id).fadeIn(2000);

  });

  $('.window .close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, .window').hide();
  });

  $('#mask').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" class="window">
  <div class="popup-left">l e f t
  </div>
  <div class="popup-right">
    <p>Запишитесь на экскурсию в комплекс «Самолет»
      <br> Укажите свои контакты, и менеджер свяжется с вами для уточнения удобного времени экскурсии.
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="close" />Закрыть его</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Суть проблемы в том, что при прямом заходе на страницу комплекса модальное окно работает в штатном режиме, как  надо. Если на страницу перейти через главную: `( home -->catalog -->jk-samolet)` Появляется проблема, модальное окно не открывается, в `url` попадает `href="id"` модального окна за счет чего происходит перезагрузка страницы. Вопрос, в какую сторону смотреть? есть подозрения на конфликт `js`. Пробовал разнообразные скрипты модального окна, результата нет.

Comment: Разберись с порядком подключения скриптов на странице, это скорее всего решит проблему)
На странице подключаются 2 jquery скрипта и при переходе по прямой ссылке в консоль падает ошибка из какого-то скрипта вставленного в тело страницы. Также делигирование событий пойдет на пользу.

Comment: Да провожу работу в этом направлении, Самое интересное то что , при прямом заходе все работает отлично, если переходить с других внутренних страниц, то возникает данная проблема, грешу на ajax... буду разбираться дальше...

Answer (score 0):

> Корень проблемы не нашел, но костыль в виде перехода на страницу в
>   новой вкладке `target="_blank"` временно решает задачу, буду
>   благодарен если кто то подскажет в чем проблема.

Нашел причину всего зла - загрузка страницы по ajax - без нее все хорошо